# undefined is not an object '_react2.PropTypes.bool'

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using react-native 0.49.5 and my application was working just fine but when I tried to install and link react-native-image-cropper it gave me an error so just to confirm if it's an issue with that library, I removed it but it is still giving me the same error:
[image]

I don't understand this error since this is all it says. Anyone has any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Did you import `PropTypes` module?

Comment: Yes, only in the app.js `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`

Comment: Any chance you could show the code that is leading to this?

Comment: I would but I have no idea what code caused this error because I didn't do any changes, this error just came out of nowhere :/

Comment: Nevermind, it was due to an outdated library I was importing. Just fixed it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please import the **PropTypes** module. it has been moved to an external package so in order to use PropTypes you'll need to import the package.

```
sudo npm install prop-types --save
```

And then reference the package like this

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

**Note** : Please remove the outdated package usage. While adding dependencies please make sure that package version is support by the react latest version.